# Creating separate class for listener

Tags: android, class, listener, textwatcher

What is the advantage of creating separate class for listener OR is there any?Which of the below code is more efficient and why?When should i create separate class?

Separate class for TextWatcher

```
mEditText.addTextChangedListener(mNumberWatcher);
TextWatcher mNumberWatcher = new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {


        }
    };
```

No Separate class

```
mEditText.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {

        }
    });
```

Comment: Use separated class can improve your code readability and also you can use that instance for another Listener too.

Comment: @Virgoir If I am not using listener code multiple times then should I use separate class?Will it effect performance?

Comment: No, its not have any performance leaks.

Comment: @Virgoir And if I don't create separate class any cons for that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use separate class for listener when it needs to use same listener several times in our code, in many no. of classes.

Comment: If I am not using listener multiple times then should I use separate class?Will it effects performance?

Comment: If you are not using it multiple times then no need to create separate class. There will be no performance issue with it.

Answer (score 0):

You should either create a separate class or inner static which ever suites your design pattern. Normal inner classes or `Anonymous` instantiations are capable of causing memory leak as they hold reference of main class and may not allow `GC` to collect it and you should avoid using them.